# Native JS app for WP8.1 can't resolve Microsoft Advertising SDK's js-file

Tags: javascript, windows-phone-8.1

I'm working on Windows Phone 8.1 native JS app and want to add one banner.

I did everything as described here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt313130(v=msads.30).aspx

But when the app is built I can see in the JS-console the following message: `APPHOST9623: The app couldn’t resolve ms-appx://microsoft.advertising.javascript/ad.js because of this error: 80070057.`

Of course the ad banner doesn't work in my app.

Additional info: I have Windows 10 on my desktop, but still use Visual Studio 2013. I tried to launch my app both inside Emulator and Device (both of them use Windows Phone 8.1), but the result is the same.

**Edit:**

I just installed Visual Studio 2015, but result is the same.